# are たときに and たら equivalent?

Tags: grammar, english-to-japanese, conditionals

I was trying to say

> I'll give you a chance when I learn to love again

I thought that I have to say something like

> 再び愛することを**学んだら**...何かする

because that time of learn how to love again will come for sure and if I remember accurately that it was the only condition to use たら as "When.." but this other sentence come to my mind too

> 再び愛することを**学んだときに**...何かする

and now I'm really confuse if there are equivalents, if there are a correct one and which? and why the other is wrong?

Comment: Can you write out the full sentence you are trying to convert into Japanese?

Comment: Um... that's a puzzling context to me. Is this person arrogantly trying to refuse to date someone? If not, can you tell me specifically under what circumstances you would want to write such a sentence?

Comment: @naruto It's not an all too unfamiliar idea to hear.  For example, someone might go through a brutal and horrendous break up and feel so wounded that they're incapable of loving anyone anymore.  So they must find some way to relearn it:  to somehow open their heart again and allow that vulnerability in.  In a manner of speaking, they're not being arrogant.  They're being very humble.  Essentially, if I heard someone say that, I would sense that they feel unworthy to be loved by anyone.  "I'll give you a chance" does sound odd, but perhaps they're afraid of being wounded all over again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

たら can be hypothetical (i.e., "if"), but たときに cannot.

- 明日雪が降ったら、...
  If it snows tomorrow...
- 明日雪が降ったときに、...
  When it snows tomorrow (and I know it will), ...

Likewise, depending on the context, 学んだら can sound like you may or may not learn something in the future. You can usually tell if a certain たら is hypothetical from the context.

That said, 学ぶ is usually used in educational contexts, and 再び愛することを学ぶ already sounds a little weird to me. Isn't something like 再び愛せるようになったら (or なったときに) enough?

Comment: You have all the reason about 学ぶ, but about the other part I have a question, If たら Always is hypothetical that typical sentence "大人になったら" means that the subject may or may not become an adult? like considering the probability of death or something like that?

Comment: @Adrian As I explained in the answer, it depends on the context. 大人になったら is probably "when", but もし明日事故で死んだら is "if". Something like いつか愛する人が出来たら can be interpreted in both ways. Please read [this article](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/conditional-form-tara/).

Answer (score 3):

たら indicates that something happens, as described in the main clause, when the circumstance described in the subordinate clause (i.e. before たら) comes true. If it is likely to happen, たら is usually translated with *when* in English, and if it is less certain, it may be translated with *if*. This is a distinction English makes. In Japanese, the basic idea is the same regardless of the likelihood.

The difference from 〜た時に is that it puts focus on a (usually one-time) condition rather than timing. For example, when you say 再び愛せるようになっ**たら**, you mean that you learning to love again is a necessary condition for doing whatever is stated in the main clause. In general, when you talk about such a condition, you are either consciously or unconsciously thinking about a possibility of it not being met. When you say 再び愛せるようになっ**た時に**, on the other hand, you are more likely assuming that that time will come.